# app stops running ios xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipod-touch

I am currently developing an IOS app using swift xcode. When I run the app initially on the device all works great. I remove/disconnect the device from mac leave it for a couple of days try to run app on device while disconnected, launch screen shows for a sec but app never opens.

Just a hunch that the app might get unverified as it is not released to the App Store, but am really just guessing here as there are not crash logs. It would be nice to know if others are having similar issues?

Comment: What's the error ? Posting a question without error is too hard to answer

Comment: @Mark Thur I know your issue, you look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38307356/iphone-app-under-test-crashes-after-a-few-days